# Where can I ask for hardware requirements for programming?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to buy a new pc for web programming. This will involve local servers, database servers, etc. And programming frameworks.

Is there somewhere I can ask about hardware specifications for this?

Note: I see some misunderstanding. Please read my question. I am not asking for a hardware recommendation. I am asking specifications for a pc that can be used for this type of programming. Just the programming and smaller tests. (At the moment I am considering tweaking Amara a bit. You can find it on GitHub. I am also considering a mix between Evernote and Zotero. Those kind of things.)

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you aren't satisfied with the score of your question: you can delete your own question only until it doesn't have multiple answers, or an upvoted answer.

Comment: Thanks @peterh, I do not have time to care about the score. ;-)

Comment: I program on a 8 yr old laptop and it work good. I don't see the need to buy a ´special' computer for this task.

Comment: Thanks @yagmoth555. Experiences like that is what I am looking for. So you are running several types of database servers and at least one web server plus some programming framework (with debuggers etc)? Can you please tell me how much RAM you have in that laptop and what processor it has?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com . It has more like a flavor seeking for hardware for special tasks, but it doesn't surely makes your question off-topic.
2. https://superuser.com . As SU mod mentioned in comments, you need to have *very careful* wording, your question shouldn't look as if you would want to avoid the hwrecs part with tricky wordings. Rather it should be really not a hardwarerecs question.

Probably you will get better answers on the SU, but your question has lesser chance to survive.

Note: your this current question is likely not enough well-detailed. Give more information about

- the frameworks you intend to use
- the development environment(s) you intend to use
- anything what details your actual work. For example, if you want to work on large-scale data collection and processing, you will likely need more disk space. If you want to work with a development environment needing a lot of RAM, you will need more RAM.

But, beware, to not make your question too specific. Questions whose answers are useful only for you, and only for now, are also discouraged on the sites.

I think it is better if you don't ask for a specific hardware, rather you ask for, *how can you choose the hardware*.

Another important advice: a review may be initiated about your question, and your first posts will be automatically reviewed on any sites. These reviews may affect the closure of your question, and new users can't see them, only the result.

Thus, if *anybody* comments your question, it is very advisable to follow his advice and edit the question as he says. Do it even if you don't see that rational - the questions should be okay on the view of the voters, your opinion is not enough for them to survive. It has also a positive effect to their voting score.

P.s. the probable essence of the answer will be this: actually any recent machine is okay, the software you are using counts more as the hw.

Comment: hardware recommendations are off topic on SU. I'd be careful about scoping on hardware recommendations SE

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ok. What if the essence of the question isn't a specific hardware, rather "how can I choose that hardware", or: what are the *requirements* for that hardware? I.e. if he doesn't ask for "which laptop should I buy", rather "what is the minimal ram to make php development with eclipse useful?"

Comment: that's still likely to be tricky - and would need VERY careful wording. My advice is always to get to know a site first before recommending it, and asking questions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek In the case of the OP, I would ask surely for this last, because there is another thing to estimate, and this is, what is the sum what I would like to invest. And this part is obviously off-topic anywhere (except maybe the Money SE). The reason, why the hw/sw recommendations are offtopic, is that they attract spam and opinionated answers. Based on the answers, it is up to the OP, how does he choose the actual things to buy.

Comment: heh, If I were building a PC, outside a few people in chat - I'd start with a budget and pick a logical increments guide build (worth googling) and chop and change from there. Its just not something SE is good at

Comment: Now, at this point, OP can ask a set of questions on HWR "I need a fast NVMe SSD at the 20 bone pricepoint in dogtopia - what are my options?"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ok, but somewhere we should start a site, and not everybody can start by answering a lot questions, before also he asks one. But I changed the order of the options and extended them with more details.

Comment: One starts not by speaking, but by listening. I always spend time looking through existing posts before posting. Seems to work for me.

Comment: I have reworded the question a bit to avoid confusion. Would this pass on SU?

Comment: @Leo - “I am asking specifications for a pc that can be used for this type of programming.” - This question wouldn’t be well received at Superuser.  How are we suppose to know what your requirements should be?  Questions seeking our recommendation does not make a good question for our Q&A format

Comment: Since I disagree that this question should be submitted at SUni have no choice but to downvote this answer

Comment: @ramhound, I think it can be answered rather easily by someone who have experience from this type of programming. Since I have not been doing this for some years I am unsure. 

How would you suggest I get this knowledge now? (I need some examples. Where can the problems be? Etc. The rest I can do myself, of course.)

Comment: Doesn’t matter if it can easily be answered it’s about if the question and and answer benefits the community.  Honestly a question about your development configuration isn’t going to help very many people other then yourself.  If you cannot determine the hardware requirements of the software you are going to run, then you have not performed enough research, on the software you plan to use.

Comment: @ramhound, thanks but of course there is no question I can not find the answer to if I do enough research. ;-)

This is actually one of the main questions people are thinking about today when they are discussing problems with fake news and bad science.

I look for cooperation, which is the only reasonable option in my opinion. The purpose of this site is cooperation. And that is what I appreciate. (Unfortunately I am doing to many different things myself to take active part here.)

Comment: @Leo Don't ask too broad questions. A possible solution for that, if you actually break up your question into multiple, narrow ones, and ask them one by one. Furthermore, by adding more details, you can make your question much narrower (beginners typically don't do this, because they think we are an answering machine knowing everything from their problem). But, if you add too many details, for example you make page-long questions, also this can have negative results.

Comment: @peterh, yes, but I do not think it fits a question like the one I have here. Experience is much more important than details here. (And that is often the case with complicated questions.)

Comment: @Ramhound Somehow your only choice is very often a downvote :-) I think, a question like "from roughly how many RAM would be php development with eclipse useful", is okay on the SU (although Journeyman SU mod says it is a border case).

Comment: @Leo I suggest either asking if your actual question is on topic over at Meta.SU or come into Root Acces and provide more details on what your actual question would be.  The question you describe currently would not be a very good fit at SU

Comment: @Leo Another way: simply ask your question, and test the community, how do they react. It would be likely closed, but you will know a lot, what do they want. But beware, you have to avoid the Q ban (and you don't have too many chance). In such case it is very important to talk with them a lot in the comments, to understand what do they say.

Comment: @peterh Excellent observation, except completely false, a question asking how much memory Eclipse would need would make a horrible question the requirements for Eclipse is right there on the Eclipse website.  You might be shocked by the fact I don’t always issue downvotes

Comment: @Ramhound These are the minimal requirements, for the eclipse PHP core, specified by their developers. From how much RAM is it *comfortable*, with all of the typical addons (which are not always even part of the eclipse distribution, but greatly affect its ram requirements), it requires somebody who actually *uses* it, not somebody who is an eclipse developer writing its user docs.

Comment: I just know if I saw a question asking what the requirements for Eclipe was, I would submit an answer which contains those requirements, because those literally are the system requirements.  I would find it difficult to answer with anything other then those requirements to remove opinionated statements from the answer

Comment: @Ramhound, you can not avoid asking for experience in situations like this. But you can avoid answering with opinions when you try to answer. Just be concrete.

Comment: @Leo I know how to answer StackExchange questions.  I have done it hundreds of times.

Comment: @Ramhound, I think that is a misunderstanding of what I said.

Comment: @Leo - "But you can avoid answering with opinions when you try to answer. Just be concrete." implies my answers are based on my opinions.

Comment: @Ramhound, conclusions based on experience etc is what I am asking for. Though you are right, you can not avoid opinions if you want to do meaningful conclusions. But you can tell what you base your conclusions on, what seems to be rather sure, what seems to be less sure.